# Deserialize Json (received from Socket.io Response) in unity

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine, deserialization

I get the data from the web server as json, but I can't deserialize them and access the keys (eg first_name)

The information is received in the client, but Unfortunately, this code does not print anything in the Unity console

my code :

```
 socket.On("UserList", response =>
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserClass>>(response.ToString());
            var first_name = result[0].first_name;
            print(first_name);
        });
```

UserClass :

```
public class UserClass
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime updateAt { get; set; }
    public int __v { get; set; }
}
```

Json that is received in the client :

```
  [
    {
      "_id": "83ca7d56cbc2b281wd4ee658",
      "first_name": "sara",
      "last_name": "Paulson",
      "mobile": "09323456789",
      "email": "sara@gmail.com",
      "createdAt": "2023-01-20T12:46:38.384Z",
      "updateAt": "2023-01-20T12:46:38.384Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "59e41dku510239e83ed7e10m",
      "first_name": "Evan",
      "last_name": "Peters",
      "mobile": "09327931248",
      "email": "Evan@gmail.com",
      "createdAt": "2023-02-10T10:35:26.687Z",
      "updateAt": "2023-02-10T10:35:26.687Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "64lm96c57a8a4f289fw0gg66",
      "first_name": "Emma",
      "last_name": "Roberts",
      "mobile": "09325354769",
      "email": "Emma@gmail.com",
      "createdAt": "2023-01-20T13:11:46.402Z",
      "updateAt": "2023-01-20T13:11:46.402Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
```

How can I access keys of this Json in Unity?

Comment: Is that a valid JSON format. JSON object should have one key and its value should be this array (I think).

Comment: Yes, I get this from the server, but the problem is that no matter what I do I can't get the values ​​individually (eg get first name values ​​or email values)

Comment: Json deserialization itselfworks as expected, you have to check other possible causes:
Whether event handler is being called at all? Whether you use right method to output value (try to use `Debug.Log()` instead)?

Comment: You can use print in Unity, I also used Debug.Log(), unfortunately I got the same result (not response or even error in the console)

Comment: Not sure but you might need to first wrap this into a JSON object `{ }` .. if you get an error .. what error do you get exactly?

Comment: For several days now, no matter what I do, the problem is not solved, no response or error is returned !

Comment: What server is this? Your own server or some other server? If they are sending JSON like this, they are doing it wrong.

Comment: It is my own server, I have written it with NodeJS, it takes the values ​​from MongoDB and sends them to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I checked and found that even specifying arrays in JSON works somehow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class UserClass
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime updateAt { get; set; }
    public int __v { get; set; }
}

class UserList
{
    public List<UserClass> objs;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string response = "{'objs': [{'_id': 1, 'first_name': 'abc'}, {'_id': 2, 'first_name': 'def'}]}";
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserList>(response);
        if (result != null)
        {
            foreach (UserClass u in result.objs)
            {
                Console.Write(u._id + ',');
                Console.WriteLine(u.first_name);
            }
        }
        string response2 = "[{'_id': 1, 'first_name': 'abc'}, {'_id': 2, 'first_name': 'def'}]";
        var result2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserClass>>(response2);
        if (result2 != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < result2.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(result2[i]._id + ',');
                Console.WriteLine(result2[i].first_name);   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both ways give same output. https://dotnetfiddle.net/g2Dn1n

The only additional thing I did was to check for returned value. You should use `Debug.Log()` in Unity to print actual values obtained after deserialization.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
But the problem is that json is not deserialized (result is empty!), it is only deserialized when I delete the <List<UserClass>>

Comment: I am receiving json using socket io, could that be the problem?

Comment: Does it throw any errors or exceptions during deserialize call? I have no idea if socket.io can cause issues. You should just debug and see if something is off in socket.io response. Maybe you can add more details in the question.